# How do I set the foreground of all label style to use my brush?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I made this color brush:

```
<!-- TEXT -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextColor"  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD9EDFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC0DEFF" Offset="0.445"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFAFD1F8" Offset="0.53"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

I am trying to set it for all label to use, but I can't figure out the syntax, here is what I have:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="{StaticResource TextColor}"  />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This throw an error saying:

```
Error   1   MarkupExtensions are not allowed for Uid or Name property values, so '{StaticResource TextColor}' is not valid.
```

WHat should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}"/>
</Style>
```